# Watermark Password box in windows 8 store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I am building a cross platform app using MVVMCROSS.

I have to use a watermark password box in my app. I tried using the excellent WinRT xaml toolkit but when i try to build the solution i get the error -

```
 "Error 40  Payload file "winrtxamltoolkit.1.6.0.3\lib\netcore45\WinRTXamlToolkit\Controls\ToolWindow\ToolWindow.xaml' does not exist"
```

So am guessing it doesnt work for netcore45 ?

Anyway I also tried using this solution http://www.julmar.com/blog/programming/adding-a-watermark-to-a-passwordbox-in-a-windows-store-app/

But unfortunately it doesnt work when i put two watermarkPasswordBoxes in a stack panel together.

Is there any working example of Watermark Password Box in WinRT XAML ?

Comment: Let me check the toolkit and update it. I'll have to go back to VS 2012 which I haven't done in a while. :)

Comment: Thank you that would be immense help!! :)

Comment: Yes, I excluded `ToolWindow` from the 8.0 package when I was trying to get it to work there. I'll update the package in a moment.

Comment: BTW, if you moved to 8.1 - there's a `PlaceholderText` property on a `PasswordBox` you could use instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I missed packaging that file into 8.0 as I mainly work on 8.1 and VS2013. It should be fixed now in 1.6.0.4. Just update your NuGet package and it should work.

Comment: Hey Filip! Thanks a lot for the update!! But after installing 1.6.0.4 today am not able to access WatermarkPasswordBox at all. Could you please check if you missed something ?

Comment: Wait its working! But the intellisense seems to be off for some reason for the controls in toolkit! Any idea if its my issue or library's ?

Comment: Not sure, it's working for me. Can you try updating to 1.6.0.5? I've had another glitch in the nuget package.

Comment: Either way thanks a ton for updating it on such short notice!! :D

Comment: One suggestion i do have for the WatermarkPasswordBox! The watermark doesnt dissappear if we go to the password box using tab! It only dissappears when u click on the password box! If possible please fix it!

Comment: I remember there was some issue with it, but I'm not sure if this can be fixed easily/quickly/at all. You can tab twice and it should work.